# If $S$ is a radicial $R-$algebra, then $\ker \left(S \otimes_R S \to S\right)$ has some idempotent element.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, tensor-products

If $S$ is a radicial $R-$algebra. This has a lot of definitions, but I'm using that if $h: R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism, then $S$ is radicial (via $h$) $R-$algebra if every element in the form $s \otimes_R 1 - 1 \otimes_R s$ is nilpotent, $\forall s \in S$.

- First of all, the author says that the Kernel of $S \otimes_R S \to S$ is generated by those elements. Well, let's call this kernel $K$. Is not hard to show that $s \otimes_R 1 - 1 \otimes_R s \in K$. The other way around, I could not do; I mean, how to prove that if $x \in K$ then its a linear combination of elements $s \otimes_R 1 - 1 \otimes_R s, s \in S$? Any tip would be helpfull.
- Now the *real deal*: The author says that $K$ contains an element $e$, where $e^2 = e$. So this is a problem, since I've tried to get some propertie around $K$, since it is an ideal, to show this element or prove that there is some idempotent one, but no success whatsoever.

Those are problems that seems simple, but I could not get through. Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance for the reading!

Comment: What's the text? Is it a paper? Book?

Comment: @Michael its a paper from J. Lipman, called Relative Lipschitz Saturation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's confirm that the elements $1 \otimes s - s \otimes 1$ do generate the kernel.

Let $ \sum a_i \otimes b_i \in S \otimes S$

Check that $\sum a_i \otimes b_i = \sum (a_i \otimes 1-1 \otimes a_i )(1  \otimes b_i) + \sum 1 \otimes a_i b_i$, and if $\sum a_i \otimes b_i$ is in the kernel of $S \otimes S \rightarrow S$, then this yields the equality $\sum a_i \otimes b_i = \sum (a_i \otimes 1-1 \otimes a_i )(1  \otimes b_i)$.

In context, the author is making a claim about a property that both radicial and unramified morphisms possess.  For convenience the author wants to use the fact that the kernel $K$ of $S \otimes S \rightarrow S$ contains an idempotent $e$ such that $K \subseteq \sqrt{e}$.  This takes a little bit of thought for unramified morphisms, but for radicial morphisms you can just take $e = 0$, since by definition a radicial morphism satisfies $K \subseteq \sqrt{0}$.

Comment: Now, the second point seems clear, thanks! But, for the first, I can't see why $\sum a_i \otimes b_i$ is equal to that linear combination; I could show that the combination is, in fact, in $K$; but how this implies the equality? There is something I am missing? Huge thanks.

Comment: In $S \otimes S$ we have $(a \otimes 1)(1 \otimes b) = a \otimes b$. The equality I wrote down follows from just expanding the product and cancelling terms. Just arithmetic, nothing deep here.

Comment: Ok, my comment was dubious, my apologies. In fact is not hard to show that $\sum a_i \otimes b_i = \sum (a_i\otimes 1 - 1\otimes a_i)(1 \otimes b_i) + \sum 1\otimes a_ib_i$; the problem, for me, is: Why is $\sum 1\otimes a_ib_i = 0$? I can only say that its in the kernel, but this map is not necessarily injective (nor surjective).

Comment: Because that element is equal to $1 \otimes \sum a_i b_i$ (again using basic properties of the tensor product)

Comment: Also, the multiplication map $S \otimes S \rightarrow S$  IS surjective, always.